# Incorrect (?) lemma returned by NLTK WordNetLemmatizer for particular words

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, lemmatization, stem

I was reading this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-text-normalizer-using-nltk-ft-pos-tagger-e713e611db8) and experimenting on my own data, I found both the examples given in the article and one of my words didn't work as described.
You can refer to the article for more information, though the question here has everything to get going.

```
# stemmed root words: Books, Braveri, Harri, Transpar
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer as Lemmatizer

# the article shared the same lemmatizer initialization.
lem = WordNetLemmatizer()

# returned 'harry' in the example without pos tag
In [269]: lem.lemmatize('harri', pos='n')
Out[269]: 'harri'

In [270]: lem.lemmatize("Books", pos='n')
Out[269]: 'Books'

# returned 'book' in the example with pos tag
In [270]: lem.lemmatize("Books", pos='v')
Out[269]: 'Books'

# my example root word, didn't change at all
[ins] In [278]: lem.lemmatize("Transpar", pos="a")
Out[278]: 'Transpar'
[ins] In [281]: lem.lemmatize("Transpar", pos="n")
Out[281]: 'Transpar'

# returned 'bravery' in the example without pos tag
[ins] In [280]: lem.lemmatize("Braveri", pos="n")
Out[280]: 'Braveri'
```

the default pos tag for this lemmatizer is just `wordnet.NOUN` therefore providing pos tag or not wouldn't make a difference.
FYI, `transpar` was originally `transparent`.

The only difference was that the author stemmed the words using NLTK stemmer whereas I was using `texthero.stem`.

Is it that I did it wrong or something has changed in NLTK?

Comment: How did you initialize `lem`?

Comment: @tripleee I initialized it with no argument, a plain `lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()`, and the article did it the same way...

Comment: Probably [edit] that into the question, and explain how your results differ from the article's so that people don't have to open them side by side to understand what you are actually asking. Your question should be self-contained anyway; links are welcome for background, but your question needs to be understandable even if the site you link to goes away or replaces the content you linked to.

Comment: just put that line into my question; I have shown the difference between what I had and what the article has shared.